# How does one import a subprocess in Windows10?

Tags: windows, tkinter

I have a tkinter program in Ubuntu. It creates and display a Prettytable from a sqlite3 database. In Linux it works perfectly but I want to provide the program to someone who runs Windows 10. One problem comes up. I cannot get the code for importing and setting the subprocess to work in Windows. Can someone possibly point me in the right direction?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from prettytable import MSWORD_FRIENDLY
import subprocess, sys
def on_Run_Rpt(self):

        import subprocess
    
        total = 0
     
        proc=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/idle-python3.9',"ExpenseReports.txt"])
```

The above is what I have in Linux but I have no idea
what the Windows equivalent is for the '/usr/bin/idle-python3.9', part or whether something different is required.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `sys.executable` instead of absolute path of Python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and while it does not raise any errors it also doesn't produce a report. I have entered proc=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable]). (If I enclose sys.executable in ' '  ie. 'sys.executable' it raises and error. Should there be further code?

Comment: Apologies. I did not add  "ExpenseReports.txt". Once I did that it seems to work. However, now it tells me in Windows that the date retrieved from the file viz.2021-12-02  has a syntax error: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted etc. The problem seems to be with the 02 of the date?

Comment: From what I have read, the above error (problem) is a Python thing. Why would it work without errors in Ubuntu but throw an error in Windows?